# have the fakeidentd.pl script listen on both ipv4 and ipv6

Tags: perl

I'm trying to update a perl script that acts as identd, to also listen on an ipv6 socket.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Socket::IP;

my($client,$socket);
if (!defined($ARGV[0])) { die "Please supply ident\n"; }
my $ident=$ARGV[0];
$socket = IO::Socket::IP->new(
        "Domain" => "PF_INET6",
        "Proto" => "tcp",
        "LocalPort" => 113,
        Reuse => 1,
        "Listen" => 1) or die "Error: $!\n";
print "using ident: $ident\n";
while ($client=$socket->accept()) {
        my $host=$client->peerhost();
        print "connection: ", $host . "\n";
        my $data = <$client>;
        if ($data) {
                print "$host recv: $data\n";
                $data =~ s/^\s+//;
                $data =~ s/\s+$//;
                $ident =~ s/^\s+//;
                $ident =~ s/\s+$//;
                print $client "$data : USERID : UNIX : $ident\n";
                close $client;
        }
}
undef $client if $client;
```

results are not satisfying at all:

> netstat -alpn | grep perl
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:113             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
$socket = IO::Socket::IP->new(
        Domain    => PF_INET6,
        LocalHost => "::1",
        "Proto" => "tcp",
        "LocalPort" => 113,
        Reuse => 1,
        "Listen" => 1) or die "Error: $!\n";
```

Result:

```
# netstat -alpn | grep perl
tcp        0      0 ::1:113                 :::*                    LISTEN      1357/perl
```

Comment: that is true
tcp6       0      0 ::1:113                 :::*                    LISTEN      7777/perl